# Error when trying to use a structure as return type

Tags: c++, struct

I am a beginner in c++ . I am trying to create a function which can resize the current array of structures. Half the way im getting this error " 'myStruct' does not name a type" and " 'resizeArray' was not declared in this scope".

```
myStruct resizeArray(myStruct * f, int * sizeOfArray);
myStruct resizeArray(myStruct * f, int * sizeOfArray)
{
    *sizeOfArray *=2;
    //things to be added

}
struct myStruct{

    string Name;
    int days;
};
int main()
{

    struct myStruct f;
    int value = 0;
    int sizeOfArray =10;
    int number_of_friends =0;
    myStruct * ptr = new myStruct [sizeOfArray];
    while(value > 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter your friends Name " << endl;
        cin >> f.Name;
        cout << "How long you know him " << endl;
        cin >> f.days;
        cout << "Do you still wanna continue ? 0 for exit , any number to continue" << endl;
        cin >> value;
    }
    resizeArray(ptr,&sizeOfArray);
    if(sizeOfArray == number_of_friends)
    {

    }
    ptr[number_of_friends] = f;
    number_of_friends++;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put the struct declaration before the function declaration/definition.

Comment: To fix the compiler error, the definition of `myStruct` must appear before you use it as a return value. However you have bigger problems coming (there is no way that `resizeArray` can change the size of the array you `new`'d in `main`  ; and it's unclear what the return value is for

Comment: Idk why people down vote for a beginner who is trying to learn something !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computers are logical things. They do things from start to finish, in order. They don't jump around, they move along in a straight line.

The very first thing the computer sees, when it reads your source file is:

```
myStruct resizeArray(myStruct * f, int * sizeOfArray);
```

The poor computer has no idea what you're talking about. It doesn't know anything about this mysterious entity called `myStruct`. It has no idea where it came from. It just started reading this file, with zero knowledge of what's in it.

So your poor computer loudly complains about it.

Please help your computer by declaring and defining your `struct`ures, before you use them. Your computer will thank you for it.

Answer (score 0):

a) You try to use the struct before you define it

b) you say you are going to return a struct but then don't.

Move this:

```
struct myStruct{

    string Name;
    int days;
};
```

To before `resizeArray()`, then either make `resizeArray()` return an appropriate value or change it's signature.

Answer (score 0):

When you define your function, your structure is not yet defined, because that happens only a few lines later. So try to put your structure definition above your function definition. Or, better yet, put it in a header file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try defining structure above resize method. But it's not only one error.